# Turtlebot depth image not showing in image_view

Tags: kinect, rviz, turtlebot, depth-registered, image-view

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to try some opencv algorithms with depth images from the turtlebot1 (create base). I want to save them for later use because of the complexity of modifying and remaking a node.

We have our Turtlebot started with Turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch and turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch. RVIZ is currently showing */camera/depth_registered/image_raw* (which dont look as detailed as I imagined looking at the IR image) but not any */camera/depth/* topic. I tried `rostopic hz /camera/depth/image_raw` but it is not publishing.
`rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/depth_registered/image_raw` says:

> Unable to convert '16UC1' image to bgr8: '[16UC1] is not a color format. but [bgr8] is. The conversion does not make sense'

Can I somehow easily save these images for later processing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/134686/turtlebot-depth-image-not-showing-in-image_view/) by [aguadopd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6283/aguadopd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2014-03-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because data format in image_raw is the depth data in mm, maybe you should try with the /camera/depth/image
If you want to use the image_raw, I think the below codes is helpful for you

```
void imageCb_d(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg)
  {
    
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;


    try
    {
      cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1);

    }
    catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
    {
      ROS_ERROR("cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
      return;
    }




    double minVal, maxVal;
    minMaxLoc(cv_ptr->image, &minVal, &maxVal); //find minimum and maximum intensities
    //Mat draw;
    cv_ptr->image.convertTo(blur_img, CV_8U, 255.0/(maxVal - minVal), -minVal * 255.0/(maxVal - minVal));



    cv::imshow("Blur", blur_img);
    cv::imshow("Depth", cv_ptr->image);

 
    cv::waitKey(3);

    image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
  }

};
```

---

Originally posted by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) with karma: 89 on 2014-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aguadopd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6283/aguadopd/) on 2014-03-04**:
Thank you! will try that. I will try using the 32bit part, since I don't want to lose resolution using 8 bit format.